# UISegmented Controller

Tags: swift

I have a segmented controll set up PROGRAMATICALLY
im trying to save the result into a String for further use

The code for the segmented Control is Below
Im having issues
Can anyone help?

```
let genderSelector: UISegmentedControl = {
   let genderSelect = UISegmentedControl()
    genderSelect.insertSegment(withTitle: "Male", at: 0, animated: true)
    genderSelect.insertSegment(withTitle: "Female", at: 1, animated: true)
    genderSelect.tintColor = UIColor.black
    return genderSelect
}()
```

Comment: What are your issues exactly? You need to define a method that receive the event when the value of the SegmentedControl changes.

Comment: so for example add a target to the segmented controller

Comment: tried declaring a global variable that stores the string corresponding the title when a segment is selected and it isn't working

Comment: I think that the SegmentedControl is within a UIViewController. So you could use an instance variable to hold the value on the SegmentedControl and when it changes the value, assign the new value to the variable.

Comment: This seems an odd way to create a UISegmentedControl with two values. Why not create the segment titles along with the control instead of using `insertSegment`? Still, if you must do things this way, create a string array of titles and have the array index correspond with the segment index. No need to overthink things - wherever you need to know the title of the selected index, just look it up in the array.

Comment: tried that it isnt working @DavidLilue

Comment: nvm i figured it out

Comment: nvm i didnt figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```
let items = ["Male", "Female"]
let customSC = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
customSC.frame = //Your Frame
customSC.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
customSC.addTarget(self, action: "yourMethod:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
self.view.addSubview(customSC)
```

Comment: thanks i appreciate that it wont let me upvote it though

Comment: If you think this helps then please accept my answer